# Connection pooling with hibernate 4 and struts2

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, c3p0

I have implemeted a web application using `Struts2 and Hibernate 4.3.5`

I am facing some problems and need some clarification on some connection pooling properties.

To make connection pooling with hibernate I have used `c3p0-0.9.1.jar`

Below are the connection pooling Properties of `c3p0` in `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
      <!-- Connection Pooling using c3p0  -->
  <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>        
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">500</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">2</property>// I heard somewhere that this property improves performance.. But  dont know How it improves
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
  <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">
  select sysdate from dual;
  </property>
```

In my application I have used * session-per-request* patterns by setting following property in `hibernte-cfg.xml`

```
        <!-- To open the connection when the request hits.  -->
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

When I use this I am getting `Session` as following

```
         //Here MyHiberantaeUtil is my own class having singleton pattern and Static block
         // To read hibernate-cfg.xml and will create SessionFactroy object.
      SessionFactory sessionFactory = MyHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();  
     Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

As per the documentation .. When I use this pattern connection should be created when request is requested and should be closed when request completed. 
For my case Its creating connection .. i.e I can get Session Using this `getCurrentSession()` But its not closing when The request ended.

To test connection pooling I have used `jconsole tool in my jdk`

Where I can see

```
   `numBusyConection = 2(If that is two requests.)`
```

I would like to know is there any thing I missed . Why `thread` property is not working as expected ?

```
  And how to say that Request has completed and request has generated ? 
  Is session-per-request is best pattern or better to go any other patterns ?
  I did not find this class `org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider` in any jar files.. But My application is connecting to DB and working fine.
```

Please help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC connection is opened when first needed and closed when the Session is closed. You need to manually close the session when you go out of your Service layer:

```
session.close();
```

Otherwise the connections won't be closed and you'll starve the connection pool.

It's a better idea to use Spring, because it has support for automatically creating/closing sessions for you. Your MyHibernateUtil is no match for what Spring has to offer:

- local transactions
- global transactions
- transaction annotations and automatic commit on success or rollback on runtime exceptions

Setting up Spring with Hibernate is as easy as using the HibernateUtil class.

Comment: For that case .. I am using this right `<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>` .. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-uow Please have look on this documentation.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't mean you don;t have to close the session yourself. This property only stores the current session in a ThreadLocal storage. For closing the current session you'd need an Aspect to intercept your service calls and Hibernate doesn't come equipped with such feature.

Comment: Okay thank you for your response.. Is there any way that we can ask hibernate to intercept ? .. cause Now I cant close them all of them through out my application... I have seen this `hibernate.auto_close_session` is it going to help me in any way .. ?

Comment: You can set that to true, even if it's not the proffered way of handling sessions.